# How to diagnose ContractFilter mismatch?

Tags: vb.net, wcf, wsdl

I've written up a server in VB.NET that consumes a providers WSDL for functionality and then hosts my own WSDL so that they can communicate with me. In testing it's been working as expect; I can consume my hosted service using SOAP-UI and WCFTestClient effortlessly.

But when our provider attempts to connect to it he received this error:

> Yadadada cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

They're not entirely helpful in resolving this issue and I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: I would start with verifying the bindings on your client and service endpoints.  If they are different in anyway, such as security settings or message size limits, then you can get a complaint about the mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After toiling away at this on and off again I realized that the provider, who was trying to access my service, was using an ASMX web service as opposed to the WCF service I had written up. Still having been a little raw to WCF I chose to just redo the work as an ASMX service and thus my problems are solved.

Trials and tribulations of an intern.